# Showing/hiding controls based on event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following code in a portion of my program that hides/shows certain elements based on the status of a certain checkbox:

```
private void enableFolderVariableRemoval_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (enableFolderVariableRemoval.Checked)
    {
        cleanFolderTextPanel.Visible = true;
        cleanTextPanel.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cleanFolderTextPanel.Visible = false;
        if (cleanFilenameTextPanel.Visible == false)
        {
            cleanTextPanel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this without a whole bunch of conditionals that set other controls to hide/show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there are any other constraints but here is one possible solution:

```
private void enableFolderVariableRemoval_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cleanFolderTextPanel.Visible = enableFolderVariableRemoval.Checked; 
    cleanTextPanel.Visible = cleanFolderTextPanel.Visible || cleanFilenameTextPanel.Visible;        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the logic is in your code, the else and nested if in it is really confusing.  But from what I can understand:

You can set the Visible Attribute for cleanFolderTextPanel straight from the checked value of enableFolderVariableRemoval.

The Visible Attribute for cleanTextPanel can then be calculated using a new Method and an inline if:

```
private void enableFolderVariableRemoval_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var enableFolderVariableRemoval = enableFolderVariableRemoval.Checked;

    cleanFolderTextPanel.Visible = enableFolderVariableRemoval;
    cleanTextPanel.Visible = CleanTextPanelShouldBeHidden(enableFolderVariableRemoval ) ? false : cleanTextPanel.Visible
}

...

private static void CleanTextPanelShouldBeHidden(bool enableFolderVariableRemoval)
{
     return !cleanFilenameTextPanel.Visible && !enableFolderVariableRemoval
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already moved your controls into logical panels, Perhaps you are asking a more general question: how do you prevent the following construct from going wild?

```
Some Event...
If GUI = 1
    Panel1.Show()
    Panel2.Hide()
    Panel3.Hide()
    ...
If GUI = 2
    Panel1.Hide()
    Panel2.Show()
    ...
If GUI = 3
    ...
```

Make the GUI `Panel`s implement a `View_I` interface which has a `.Show()` and `.Hide()` methods, then the code becomes more like:

```
Some Event...
// hide the previous View if one exists
If View_I != Null
    View_I.Hide()

If GUI = 1
    View_I = Panel1
If GUI = 2
   View_I = Panel2
    ...
// Show the new View
View_I.Show() 
    ...
```

Now you can add other `Panels` without code management proliferation.